# Wired Connection Not Working, Ethernet Cable Works Properly

Tags: internet, ethernet, dhcp, ipv4

I just performed a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on my HP workstation, however the wired ethernet connection doesn't work, even though the ethernet cable works (tested on a different workstation and it works fine) and Ubuntu does say I am connected to the internet (Wired Connected, however there is a question mark over the Ethernet icon).

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
Fron 192.168.0.51 icmp seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.51 icmp seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.51 icmp seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
Fron 192.168.0.51 icmp seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
Fron 192.168.0.51 icmp seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
8.8.8.8 ping statistics
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, +5 errors, 100% packet loss, time 5047ns
```

```
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
  inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 ::1/128 scope host
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
  link/ether a0:d3:c1:0d:96:ae brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 192.168.0.51/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno1
    valid_lft 86233sec preferred_lft 86233sec
  inet6 fe80::8bed:df85:c0cf:f771/64 scope link noprefixroute
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yanl

network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
```

Unfortunately the workstation does not have a wifi card nor am I able to get a usb dongle wifi card, any and all help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

**EDIT 1**

```
ip route

default via 192.168.0.1 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 20100
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno1 scope link metric 1000
192.168.0.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.51 metric 100
```

```
service NetworkManager status
NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/systen/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Tue 2023-03-07 21:44:00 GMT: 49min ago
Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
Main PID: 614 (NetworkManager)
Tasks: 3 (limit: 19017)
Memory: 14.8M
CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
L614 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
Mar 07 22:25:39 js-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF NetworkManager[614]: <info> [1678227939.1866] dhcp4 (eno1): option routers
=> '192.168.0.1'
Mar 07 22:25:39 js-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF NetworkManager[614]: <info> [1678227939.1866] dhcp4 (eno1): option subnet_mask
=> '255.255.255.0'
Mar 07 22:25:39 js-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF NetworkManager[614]: <info> [1678227939.1866] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed unknown -> bound
Mar 07 22:25:39 js-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF NetworkManager[614]: <info> [1678227939.1920] device (eno1): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 07 22:25:39 js-HP-EllteDesk-800-G1-SFF NetworkManager[614]: <info> [1678227939.2034] device (eno1): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: "managed')
Mar 07 22:25:39 js-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF NetworkManager[614]: <info> [1678227939.2036] device (eno1): state change: secondariles -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mar 07 22:25:39 js-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF NetworkManager[614]: <info> [1678227939.2040] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Mar 07 22:25:39 js-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF NetworkManager[614]: <info> [1678227939.2046] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Mar 07 22:25:39 js-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF NetworkManager[614]: <info> [1678227939.2046] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (eno1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Mar 07 22:25:39 js-HP-EliteDesk-800-G1-SFF NetworkManager[614]: <info> [1678227939.2049] device (eno1): Activation: successful, device activated.
```

```
ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.51 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.51 icmp_seq-2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.51 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.51 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
192.168.0.1 ping statistics
5 packets transmitted, 6 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, tine 4041ns
```

Comment: Please add the output of `ip route`. This looks like a network issue rather than an Ubuntu issue.

Comment: Also look at `service NetworkManager  status`.

Comment: @zwets thank you so much for the help, I added the relevant info

Comment: And does `ping 192.168.0.1` work? Please add its output to the question.

Comment: @zwets ```ping 192.168.0.1``` yields ```Destination Host Unreachable```

Comment: @zwets updated with the relevant info, many thanks again!

Comment: Does the weirdly large metric (20100) on the default route look strange, or is it just me?

Comment: The issue is that your gateway is unreachable. This has nothing to do with Ubuntu. You might try rebooting your router. Also, try plugging the ethernet cable in another port on the router. Could it be you have plugged it into the ISP side, rather than the LAN side?

Comment: @zwets thank you for your answer. I tried both rebooting the router and changing the port, and still nothing. As an aside, when i tried plugging a different (Windows) machine into the router using the exact same port and cable, I was able to connect to the internet. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your gateway is unreachable. This has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

You might try rebooting your router. Also, try plugging the ethernet cable in another port on the router. Could it be that you have plugged it into the WAN (ISP) side, rather than the LAN side?

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried both rebooting the router and changing the port, and still nothing. As an aside, when i tried plugging a different machine into the router using the exact same port and cable, I was able to connect to the internet. Is there anything else I can do?